# ¿Cómo ajusto el alto de cada fila de un jsTree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

Utilizo el **plugin [jstree](https://www.jstree.com/)**, a ello le agregue una **extension** llamada [**jstree-table**](https://github.com/adamjimenez/jstree-table), esto para poder manejar columnas en cada nivel.

```js
// tree data
var data;
data = [{
  text: "Products",
  data: {},
  children: [{
    text: "Fruit",
    data: {}, 
    children:[
      {text: "Apple", data: {price: 0.1, quantity: 20}},
      {text: "Banana", data: {price: 0.2, quantity: 31}},
      {text: "Grapes", data: {price: 1.99, quantity: 34}},
      {text: "Mango", data: {price: 0.5, quantity: 8}},
      {text: "Melon", data: {price: 0.8, quantity: 4}},
      {text: "Pear", data: {price: 0.1, quantity: 30}},
      {text: "Strawberry", data: {price: 0.15, quantity: 32}}
    ],
    'state': {'opened': true}
  }, {
    text: "Vegetables",
    data: {}, 
    children:[
      {text: "Aubergine", data: {price: 0.5, quantity: 8}},
      {text: "Broccoli", data: {price: 0.4, quantity: 22}},
      {text: "Carrot", data: {price: 0.1, quantity: 32}},
      {text: "Cauliflower", data: {price: 0.45, quantity: 18}},
      {text: "Potato", data: {price: 0.2, quantity: 38}}
    ]
  }],
  'state': {'opened': true}
}];

// load jstree
$("div#jstree").jstree({
  plugins: ["table","sort"],
  core: {
    data: data
  },
  // configure tree table
  table: {
    columns: [
      {height: 200, header: "Name"},
      {height: 200, value: "price", header: "Price", format: function(v) {if (v){ return '$'+v.toFixed(2) }}},
      {height: 200, value: "quantity", header: "Qty"},
      {height: 200, value: "price", header: "Price",
       format: function(v) {
          let div_partes = $('<div/>',{
            'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
          });
          div_field = $('<div/>',{
            'class' : 'col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
          });
          let field_cant = $('<input/>',{
            'type' : 'number',
            'id' : v,
            'name' : 'planes',
            'tipo' : 'cant',
            'step' : '1',
            'pattern' : '[0-9]+([\,][0-9]+)?',
            'min' : '0',
            'style' : 'width: 100%;',
          });
          field_cant.appendTo(div_field);
          div_field.appendTo(div_partes);
          div_field = $('<div/>',{
            'class' : 'col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
          });
          let field_tipo = $('<select/>',{
            'id' : v,
            'name' : 'planes',
            'style' : 'width: 100%;',
          });
          let options;
          options = $('<option/>',{
            'value' : 0,
            'text' : 'Hora(s)',
          });
          options.appendTo(field_tipo);
          options = $('<option/>',{
            'value' : 1,
            'text' : 'Día(s)',
          });
          options.appendTo(field_tipo);
          options = $('<option/>',{
            'value' : 2,
            'text' : 'Mes(es)',
          });
          options.appendTo(field_tipo);
          options = $('<option/>',{
            'value' : 3,
            'text' : 'Año(s)',
          });
          options.appendTo(field_tipo);
          field_tipo.appendTo(div_field);
          div_field.appendTo(div_partes);
          return div_partes;
        }
      },
    ],
    resizable: true,
    draggable: true,
    contextmenu: true,
    width: 500,
    height: 300
  }
});
```

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
body {
  margin: 1em;
}
.jstree-table-wrapper:hover {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://static.jstree.com/latest/assets/dist/jstree.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://static.jstree.com/3.3.0/assets/dist/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/adamjimenez/jstree-table/master/jstreetable.js"></script>

<div id="jstree"></div>
```

En este ejemplo tengo elementos **checkbox, select e inputs**, el problema es que los **selects e inputs** abarcan mucho espacio y las filas no se ajustan al tamaño de la ultima columna (la cual contiene dichos elementos -**selects e inputs**-).

#### Actualización 1:

Colocando estilos `bootstrap` para que coincida con mi proyecto se desorganiza todo.

```js
// tree data
var data;
data = [{
  text: "Products",
  data: {},
  children: [{
    text: "Fruit",
    data: {}, 
    children:[
      {text: "Apple", data: {price: 0.1, quantity: 20}},
      {text: "Banana", data: {price: 0.2, quantity: 31}},
      {text: "Grapes", data: {price: 1.99, quantity: 34}},
      {text: "Mango", data: {price: 0.5, quantity: 8}},
      {text: "Melon", data: {price: 0.8, quantity: 4}},
      {text: "Pear", data: {price: 0.1, quantity: 30}},
      {text: "Strawberry", data: {price: 0.15, quantity: 32}}
    ],
    'state': {'opened': true}
  }, {
    text: "Vegetables",
    data: {}, 
    children:[
      {text: "Aubergine", data: {price: 0.5, quantity: 8}},
      {text: "Broccoli", data: {price: 0.4, quantity: 22}},
      {text: "Carrot", data: {price: 0.1, quantity: 32}},
      {text: "Cauliflower", data: {price: 0.45, quantity: 18}},
      {text: "Potato", data: {price: 0.2, quantity: 38}}
    ]
  }],
  'state': {'opened': true}
}];

// load jstree
$("div#jstree").jstree({
  plugins: ["table","sort"],
  core: {
    data: data
  },
  // configure tree table
  table: {
    columns: [
      {header: "Name"},
      {value: "price", header: "Price",
       format: function(v) {
          let div_partes = $('<div/>',{
            'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
          });
          div_field = $('<div/>',{
            'class' : 'col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
          });
          let field_cant = $('<input/>',{
            'type' : 'number',
            'id' : v,
            'name' : 'planes',
            'tipo' : 'cant',
            'step' : '1',
            'class' : 'form-control',
            'pattern' : '[0-9]+([\,][0-9]+)?',
            'min' : '0',
            'style' : 'width: 47%; margin: 0 2px',
          });
          field_cant.appendTo(div_field);
          let field_tipo = $('<select/>',{
            'id' : v,
            'name' : 'planes',
            'class' : 'form-control',
            'style' : 'width: 47%; margin: 0 2px',
          });
          let options;
          options = $('<option/>',{
            'value' : null,
            'text' : 'Elija...',
          });
          options.appendTo(field_tipo);
          options = $('<option/>',{
            'value' : 0,
            'text' : 'Hora(s)',
          });
          options.appendTo(field_tipo);
          options = $('<option/>',{
            'value' : 1,
            'text' : 'Día(s)',
          });
          options.appendTo(field_tipo);
          options = $('<option/>',{
            'value' : 2,
            'text' : 'Mes(es)',
          });
          options.appendTo(field_tipo);
          options = $('<option/>',{
            'value' : 3,
            'text' : 'Año(s)',
          });
          options.appendTo(field_tipo);
          field_tipo.appendTo(div_field);
          div_field.appendTo(div_partes);
          
          field_tipo.select2();
          
          return div_partes;
        }
      },
    ],
    resizable: true,
    draggable: true,
    contextmenu: true,
    width: 500,
    height: 300
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://static.jstree.com/latest/assets/dist/jstree.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://static.jstree.com/3.3.0/assets/dist/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/adamjimenez/jstree-table/master/jstreetable.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="jstree"></div>
```

Comment: Hola Pablo. Te refieres a que cada selecte esté alineado con su respectiva fila no?

Comment: @lois6b Si a eso me refiero.

Comment: De todas formas no esta bien. Cuando le das a ordenar se resetean los inputs etc

Comment: @GDP no entendi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es un problema de cómo creas el contenido de la celda. Cada control (`input`, `select`) lo metes en un `div` que ocupa todo el ancho disponible debido a los estilos de bootstrap que les aplicas.

Puedes crear un único `div` en el que incluir ambos controles:

```js
// tree data
var data;
data = [{
  text: "Products",
  data: {},
  children: [{
    text: "Fruit",
    data: {}, 
    children:[
      {text: "Apple", data: {price: 0.1, quantity: 20}},
      {text: "Banana", data: {price: 0.2, quantity: 31}},
      {text: "Grapes", data: {price: 1.99, quantity: 34}},
      {text: "Mango", data: {price: 0.5, quantity: 8}},
      {text: "Melon", data: {price: 0.8, quantity: 4}},
      {text: "Pear", data: {price: 0.1, quantity: 30}},
      {text: "Strawberry", data: {price: 0.15, quantity: 32}}
    ],
    'state': {'opened': true}
  }, {
    text: "Vegetables",
    data: {}, 
    children:[
      {text: "Aubergine", data: {price: 0.5, quantity: 8}},
      {text: "Broccoli", data: {price: 0.4, quantity: 22}},
      {text: "Carrot", data: {price: 0.1, quantity: 32}},
      {text: "Cauliflower", data: {price: 0.45, quantity: 18}},
      {text: "Potato", data: {price: 0.2, quantity: 38}}
    ]
  }],
  'state': {'opened': true}
}];

// load jstree
$("div#jstree").jstree({
  plugins: ["table","sort"],
  core: {
    data: data
  },
  // configure tree table
  table: {
    columns: [
      {height: 200, header: "Name"},
      {height: 200, value: "price", header: "Price", format: function(v) {if (v){ return '$'+v.toFixed(2) }}},
      {height: 200, value: "quantity", header: "Qty"},
      {height: 200, value: "price", header: "Price",
       format: function(v) {
          let div_partes = $('<div/>',{
            'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
          });
          div_field = $('<div/>',{
            'class' : 'col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
          });
          let field_cant = $('<input/>',{
            'type' : 'number',
            'id' : v,
            'name' : 'planes',
            'tipo' : 'cant',
            'step' : '1',
            'pattern' : '[0-9]+([\,][0-9]+)?',
            'min' : '0',
            'style' : 'width: 47%; margin: 0 2px',
          });
          field_cant.appendTo(div_field);
          let field_tipo = $('<select/>',{
            'id' : v,
            'name' : 'planes',
            'style' : 'width: 47%; margin: 0 2px',
          });
          let options;
          options = $('<option/>',{
            'value' : 0,
            'text' : 'Hora(s)',
          });
          options.appendTo(field_tipo);
          options = $('<option/>',{
            'value' : 1,
            'text' : 'Día(s)',
          });
          options.appendTo(field_tipo);
          options = $('<option/>',{
            'value' : 2,
            'text' : 'Mes(es)',
          });
          options.appendTo(field_tipo);
          options = $('<option/>',{
            'value' : 3,
            'text' : 'Año(s)',
          });
          options.appendTo(field_tipo);
          field_tipo.appendTo(div_field);
          div_field.appendTo(div_partes);
          return div_partes;
        }
      },
    ],
    resizable: true,
    draggable: true,
    contextmenu: true,
    width: 500,
    height: 300
  }
});
```

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
body {
  margin: 1em;
}
.jstree-table-wrapper:hover {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://static.jstree.com/latest/assets/dist/jstree.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://static.jstree.com/3.3.0/assets/dist/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/adamjimenez/jstree-table/master/jstreetable.js"></script>

<div id="jstree"></div>
```

Otra opción utilizando los estilos de bootstrap aunque usarlos seguramente te genere problemas al mezclar los estilos de bootstrap con los de las celdas del jstree.

Por ejemplo he quitado la clase `form-group` porque ésta incluye un `margin` que obliga a redimensionar el alto de las celdas y te iba a desalinear las filas.

```js
// tree data
var data;
data = [{
  text: "Products",
  data: {},
  children: [{
    text: "Fruit",
    data: {}, 
    children:[
      {text: "Apple", data: {price: 0.1, quantity: 20}},
      {text: "Banana", data: {price: 0.2, quantity: 31}},
      {text: "Grapes", data: {price: 1.99, quantity: 34}},
      {text: "Mango", data: {price: 0.5, quantity: 8}},
      {text: "Melon", data: {price: 0.8, quantity: 4}},
      {text: "Pear", data: {price: 0.1, quantity: 30}},
      {text: "Strawberry", data: {price: 0.15, quantity: 32}}
    ],
    'state': {'opened': true}
  }, {
    text: "Vegetables",
    data: {}, 
    children:[
      {text: "Aubergine", data: {price: 0.5, quantity: 8}},
      {text: "Broccoli", data: {price: 0.4, quantity: 22}},
      {text: "Carrot", data: {price: 0.1, quantity: 32}},
      {text: "Cauliflower", data: {price: 0.45, quantity: 18}},
      {text: "Potato", data: {price: 0.2, quantity: 38}}
    ]
  }],
  'state': {'opened': true}
}];

// load jstree
$("div#jstree").jstree({
  plugins: ["table","sort"],
  core: {
    data: data
  },
  // configure tree table
  table: {
    columns: [
      {height: 200, header: "Name"},
      {height: 200, value: "price", header: "Price", format: function(v) {if (v){ return '$'+v.toFixed(2) }}},
      {height: 200, value: "quantity", header: "Qty"},
      {height: 200, value: "price", header: "Price",
       format: function(v) {
          let div_partes = $('<div/>',{
            'class' : 'row',
          });
          div_field = $('<div/>',{
            'class' : 'col-sm-6 col-xs-6',
          });
          let field_cant = $('<input/>',{
            'type' : 'number',
            'id' : v,
            'name' : 'planes',
            'tipo' : 'cant',
            'step' : '1',
            'pattern' : '[0-9]+([\,][0-9]+)?',
            'min' : '0',
            'style': 'width: 100%; line-height: normal;'
          });
          field_cant.appendTo(div_field);
          div_field.appendTo(div_partes);
          div_field = $('<div/>',{
            'class' : 'col-sm-6 col-xs-6',
          });
          let field_tipo = $('<select/>',{
            'id' : v,
            'name' : 'planes',
            'style': 'width: 100%;'
          });
          let options;
          options = $('<option/>',{
            'value' : 0,
            'text' : 'Hora(s)',
          });
          options.appendTo(field_tipo);
          options = $('<option/>',{
            'value' : 1,
            'text' : 'Día(s)',
          });
          options.appendTo(field_tipo);
          options = $('<option/>',{
            'value' : 2,
            'text' : 'Mes(es)',
          });
          options.appendTo(field_tipo);
          options = $('<option/>',{
            'value' : 3,
            'text' : 'Año(s)',
          });
          options.appendTo(field_tipo);
          field_tipo.appendTo(div_field);
          div_field.appendTo(div_partes);
          return div_partes;
        }
      },
    ],
    resizable: true,
    draggable: true,
    contextmenu: true,
    width: 500,
    height: 300
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 1em;
}
.jstree-table-wrapper:hover {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://static.jstree.com/latest/assets/dist/jstree.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://static.jstree.com/3.3.0/assets/dist/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/adamjimenez/jstree-table/master/jstreetable.js"></script>

<div id="jstree"></div>
```

**Actualización 1**

Es un ejemplo de lo que te comentaba más arriba: las librerías como bootstrap son muy cómodas para desarrollar rápido pero incluyen un gran número de estilos que te pueden causar muchos problemas cuando quieres personalizar la visualización.

En tu caso tienes estilos incluidos por bootstrap, jsTree y select2. Al final, más que definir reglas de estilo, lo que te ves obligado es a anular las que te incluyen cada una de las librerías y que chocan unas con otras.

Aquí tienes una nueva versión que trata de hacer esto último basándose en tu último código. Espero que te sirva:

```js
// tree data
var data;
data = [{
  text: "Products",
  data: {},
  children: [{
    text: "Fruit",
    data: {}, 
    children:[
      {text: "Apple", data: {price: 0.1, quantity: 20}},
      {text: "Banana", data: {price: 0.2, quantity: 31}},
      {text: "Grapes", data: {price: 1.99, quantity: 34}},
      {text: "Mango", data: {price: 0.5, quantity: 8}},
      {text: "Melon", data: {price: 0.8, quantity: 4}},
      {text: "Pear", data: {price: 0.1, quantity: 30}},
      {text: "Strawberry", data: {price: 0.15, quantity: 32}}
    ],
    'state': {'opened': true}
  }, {
    text: "Vegetables",
    data: {}, 
    children:[
      {text: "Aubergine", data: {price: 0.5, quantity: 8}},
      {text: "Broccoli", data: {price: 0.4, quantity: 22}},
      {text: "Carrot", data: {price: 0.1, quantity: 32}},
      {text: "Cauliflower", data: {price: 0.45, quantity: 18}},
      {text: "Potato", data: {price: 0.2, quantity: 38}}
    ]
  }],
  'state': {'opened': true}
}];

// load jstree
$("div#jstree").jstree({
  plugins: ["table","sort"],
  core: {
    data: data
  },
  // configure tree table
  table: {
    columns: [
      {header: "Name"},
      {value: "price", header: "Price",
       format: function(v) {
          let div_partes = $('<div/>',{
            'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
            'style' : 'margin: 0; padding: 0;'
          });
          div_field = $('<div/>',{
            'class' : 'col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
          });
          let field_cant = $('<input/>',{
            'type' : 'number',
            'id' : v,
            'name' : 'planes',
            'tipo' : 'cant',
            'step' : '1',
            'class' : 'form-control',
            'pattern' : '[0-9]+([\,][0-9]+)?',
            'min' : '0',
            'style' : 'width: 47%; margin: 0 2px; display: inline-block; height: 22px;',
          });
          field_cant.appendTo(div_field);
          let field_tipo = $('<select/>',{
            'id' : v,
            'name' : 'planes',
            'class' : 'form-control',
            'style' : 'width: 47%; margin: 0',
          });
          let options;
          options = $('<option/>',{
            'value' : null,
            'text' : 'Elija...',
          });
          options.appendTo(field_tipo);
          options = $('<option/>',{
            'value' : 0,
            'text' : 'Hora(s)',
          });
          options.appendTo(field_tipo);
          options = $('<option/>',{
            'value' : 1,
            'text' : 'Día(s)',
          });
          options.appendTo(field_tipo);
          options = $('<option/>',{
            'value' : 2,
            'text' : 'Mes(es)',
          });
          options.appendTo(field_tipo);
          options = $('<option/>',{
            'value' : 3,
            'text' : 'Año(s)',
          });
          options.appendTo(field_tipo);
          field_tipo.appendTo(div_field);
          div_field.appendTo(div_partes);
          
          field_tipo.select2();
          
          return div_partes;
        }
      },
    ],
    resizable: true,
    draggable: true,
    contextmenu: true,
    width: 500,
    height: 300
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 1em;
}
/* Make Select2 boxes match Bootstrap3 heights: */
.jstree-default .select2-selection__rendered {
  line-height: 20px !important;
}

.jstree-default .select2-selection {
  height: 22px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://static.jstree.com/latest/assets/dist/jstree.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://static.jstree.com/3.3.0/assets/dist/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/adamjimenez/jstree-table/master/jstreetable.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="jstree"></div>
```

Comment: Quisiera mantener los estilos de formulario de **bootstrap**, en mi sistema de hecho se ven algo mas grandes ya que el `select` le coloque **select2** (es el estilo que tengo en todos los `selects`, ¿Seria buena practica meter los estilos como lo intento? ó ¿No hay de otra?

Comment: He añadido un ejemplo manteniendo clases de bootstrap pero, como te indico en la respuesta, es muy probable que te encuentres con problemas al "chocar" los estilos definidos en bootstrap con los del jstree

Comment: Actualice mi pregunta para que veas con un poco de `boostrap` a los elementos.

Comment: He añadido un ejemplo basándome en tu última actualización. Realmente es muy complicado conseguir ajustar el resultado teniendo tantos estilos aplicados por las diferentes librerías.

Comment: Es lo que buscaba, gracias hermano.

Comment: Mas tarde cuando este en mi PC doy mi aprobación de la respuesta.

Comment: ¿Como puedo colocarle ese estilo solo a los que están en el `jstree` y que no afecte los que están afuera del mismo?

Comment: Basta con que prefijes las reglas css con alguna clase propia del `jstree` como `.jstree-default`. Edito el ejemplo para mostrarlo.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda.